# Tens of "external abort on non-linefetch (0x1018)" kernel messages on a CycloneV's embedded linux

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, intel-fpga

I'm working on C++ program running on a custom Linux distro running on an Altera CycloneV FPGA.

When I print a complete page to the tty (accessed through a serial port on a Windows PC) I get a lot of these messages:

```
Unhandled fault: external abort on non-linefetch (0x1018) at (address)
```

(address) being a lot of consecutive addresses, always different ones

I'm looking for the cause of these messages. It overflows the /dev/kmsg buffer and I'm worried it could cause of some other bug in my program

Comment: I suppose these address are mapped to FPGA registers? I would say this error is produced by MMU because FPGA doesn't have expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time but I found an answer: those messages are debug messages generated by the kernel and are completely harmless. Lowering the logging level made them disappear.